# Explain saw and have seen

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

I met a coworker at a bar and I said "I saw you last week at the gas station".

He replied with "I have seen you too but didn't want to bother you." 
Why didn't he use "I saw you too..."?

Comment: If it a gas station you both frequent, perhaps he is saying he has seen you there more than one.  Otherwise, if he is a native speaker, is it possible that you misheard him, and he actually said "I may have seen you too, but didn't want to bother you."  The "m" in _may_ could be a small sound.  It wouldn't be perfect grammatically, but it wouldn't be terrible, either.

Comment: @Adam I think this is the correct answer. *Have seen* as used here normally means more than once, whereas *saw* refers to a single event.

Answer (score 1):

"I have seen you too" indicates that the speaker isn't refering to a single instance but has seen him on several occasions.

"I saw you too" indicates that he is talking about that particular time, last week, the first speaker is refering to.

Comment: you should elaborate a bit more. :)

Answer (score 0):

The word *saw* is used when the speaker is talking about themselves or something like that, as in:
Hey, I *saw* you at that rock concert last night. 
*Have seen* can be used for multiple things, as in:
I *have seen* you several times at school. *Saw* would be used when talking about one thing. But they both can be used for single or plural things. Also, *saw* would be used when you are talking about a time period that has finished. Have seen is used when the time period is not over. As in:
I *saw* three movies *last week*. 
I *have seen* three movies *this week*.